# Html 5 video tag is not displayed only in iphones (safari browser )

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, html5-video

In my project there before login the video will not have any controls and no autoplay , after login controls will be present . 
If I add autoplay attribute , I can see the html 5 video player in all device including iphone , however if I remove the autoplay attribute html 5 video player will be a white blank page ..

Comment: We can only guess...hmm.. did you add `controls` attribute?

Comment: We have removed the controls before login , our requirement is before login only video poster mst be seen and total duration of the video mst be visible , video should not autoplay or shld not have any controls

Answer (score 0):

I added #t=0.1 and preload = metadata.[image]

#t=0.1" type="video/mp4">